# ExtJS 5 bind toggle button to multiple components state

Tags: extjs, mvvm, data-binding

I'm working with ExtJS 5 and I need to bind the **pressed** config of a toggle button to the same config of an arbitrary array of another toggle buttons. In other words it should be something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    alias : 'widget.myPanel',

    requires : ['path to viewmodel'],

    viewModel : {
        type : 'myPanel'
    },

    items : [
        {
            xtype : 'button',
            reference : 'btn1',
            enableToggle : true
        },
        {
            xtype : 'button',
            reference : 'btn2',
            enableToggle : true
        },
        // ... bunch of other buttons
        {
            xtype : 'button',
            enableToggle : true,
            bind : {
                pressed : '{btn1.pressed && btn2.pressed}'
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

Furthermore I should be able to dinamically add or remove components to the dependend toggle button. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think it needs more coding using `formulas`. Btw, what would be a use case?

Comment: @Saki I have to build a grid of 90 toggle buttons controlling an underlying array of numbers. One could add or remove a number from the array by pressing/depressing the appropriate toggle button. Then I have other buttons applying custom constraints over the array (even, odd, first half, second half etc.) and I need those last buttons to control the first ones.

Comment: @Saki Anyway I realized that this is not the purpose of ViewModel so I implemented the custom logic in the controller.